# Xcode storyboard image view resizing error

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I don't know what's wrong with Xcode, or perhaps I do it wrong.

First, ----> [Please check this VIDEO](http://youtu.be/sO5MKBtATgQ) just 20sec.

This is what I got,

[image]

I use the same exact settings on those icon. But the like icon image view behave differently.

Comment: What's wrong with you guys? I never seen anything like this with Xcode before, that's why I upload the video and ask.

Comment: Don't take it too personally m8, Life's good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select your tableview cell(double click on cell) and  uncheck the AutoResizeSubviews Option  in attributes inspector

[image]

Comment: I try to disable autoresize subviews on the cell and image view, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Change your size inspector to looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm using auto layout. I try to turn auto layout off, and got this.
http://i.imgur.com/Ez893M7.png

Comment: Ok,  don't like auto layout neither. For each subView u should do the size inspector as the pic shown.